# How to insert Data into IndexedDB within an AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, indexeddb

lets say I have a the following code that creates the database OUTSIDE of my Ajax call:

```
// This works on all devices/browsers, and uses IndexedDBShim as a final fallback 
var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB || window.shimIndexedDB;

// Open (or create) the database
var open = indexedDB.open("MyDatabase", 1);

// Create the schema
open.onupgradeneeded = function() {
    var db = open.result;
    var store = db.createObjectStore("MyObjectStore", {keyPath: "id"});
    var index = store.createIndex("NameIndex", ["name.last", "name.first"]);
};
```

and then I want to store some data into this database within my Ajax call like so:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "https://sometise.com,
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "TOKEN"
        },
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {

$(data).each(function (index, el) {

var myArray = {
            ID: el.id,
            Content: data
          }
///ADDING THE ABOVE ARRAY TO THE DATABASE LIKE SO HERE


open.onsuccess = function() {
    // Start a new transaction
    var db = open.result;
    var tx = db.transaction("MyObjectStore", "readwrite");
    var store = tx.objectStore("MyObjectStore");
    var index = store.index("NameIndex");

    // Add some data
    store.put({id: el.id, name: {first: myArray, last: "Doe"}});
    

    // Close the db when the transaction is done
    tx.oncomplete = function() {
        db.close();
    };
}


});


}

  });
```

but the above code doesn't do anything!

any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `open.onsuccess` event gets fired only once. This should happen as soon as the DB is ready, which likely happens before the ajax call receives a response from the server. So the event gets fired before you attach the listener, meaning it never gets handled.

You have to store the `onsuccess` result outside of the ajax callback. Or you can use a promisified version of IDB like https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb and `await` it inside the ajax callback.

Edit: An example using promises, await and the idb library I mentioned above:

```
const db = openDB(…);

async function doPost() {
  const response = fetch('https://somesite.com')
  
  const tx = (await db).transaction("MyObjectStore", "readwrite");
  const store = tx.objectStore("MyObjectStore");
  const index = store.index("NameIndex");

  // Add some data
  await store.put(await response);
  await tx.done;
}
```

Should work like this, but I would recommend reading up about promises in general. Also consider using modern language features like const/let and fetch, they usually make live much easier.

Comment: Do you mind elaborate by a code example?

Comment: I seem to be able to open the open.onsuccess multiple times!

Comment: Added an code example how it might look using async/await with promises.